# Raspberry PI not picking up Logitech C270

Tags: camera, connection

I am currently struggling because my Raspberry Pi is unable to connect to the webcam. Running `lsusb` never shows anything (keeps loading) and `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` says `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.`

The connected cord is not the stock one although it outputs 5&nsp;V & 2.5 A. I heard you should use a USB hub although I don't want to spend another $20 on one (if possible).

What could be the issue?

Comment: *"Running lsusb never shows anything (keeps loading)"* -> Can you explain what you mean by this in more detail?  It does not sound right.  Try it, then immediately afterward `sudo tail /var/log/syslog` and/or: Open a separate terminal and `sudo journalctl -f` (this will block), then from another run `lsusb` and see if there are any system errors being logged for this.

Comment: It isn't outputting anything trying both strategies

Comment: If you mean there is nothing in those logs, there is a lot more wrong than just no USB cam...

Comment: What could be wrong @goldilocks

Answer (score 0):

There are certain types of cables. I have run into a similar issue too, when my Pico did not connect to my computer, and did not recgonize anything. There are usb cables of power only, and there are cables for power AND transferring data. I believe you are using a power only usb cable, and therefore it is not showing up. I suggest getting a different cable that is specifically for transferring power AND data, as a computer wont show a charging cable as a plugged in USB.

Comment: I would think the USB cable is permanently attached at the camera end.

Comment: Yeah the USB cable is permanently attached